# Python: Get different time format

Tags: python

How do I get the time formatted like `16:13:34` (hours:minutes:seconds) instead of `Fri Feb 15 16:13:55 2013` when I use `time.asctime()`? And is there a way to return the time as shown in the first example (`16:13:14`)?

**Edit:** I have tried the following:

```
>>> local = time.gmtime("tm_hour") + ":" + time.gmtime("tm_min") + ":" + time.gm_time("tm_sec")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the current HH:MM:SS time, use this:

```
time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module for this. If you want to get the current time in the given format use

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```